# Locally prevent page break after a displayed equation

Tags: equations, page-breaking, widows-orphans

In my document, sometimes there is a sentence like `The diagram <tikz-cd diagram here> commute.`, in which case there is only one word after the displayed equation. I would like to make sure that this word does not appear on the top of the next page. I checked [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3259/how-to-avoid-widow-lines-after-displayed-equations), but the solution there does not work in my document.

I'm aware that in the final version, this problem can be solved with `\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}`. However, documents like course notes are quite dynamic and they hardly reach a "final" state, so using and maintaining these `\enlargethispage` can be a problem.

The code below serves as a MWE. It is not an exact replication of my actual situation -- in fact, not like in this MWE, there are enough space to place that single word in my document, yet LaTeX decides that there should be a page break anyway.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe,margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{24.5cm}
% \enlargethispage{\baselineskip}

The diagram
\[
    \begin{tikzcd}
        \bullet & \bullet \\
        \bullet & \bullet
        \arrow[from=1-1, to=1-2]
        \arrow[from=2-1, to=2-2]
        \arrow[from=1-1, to=2-1]
        \arrow[from=1-2, to=2-2]
    \end{tikzcd}
\]
commute.

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

> Below is the screenshot of my actual document (the space between the
> text and the footer is usually quite small, so there should be enough
> place for this single word):
>
> [image]
>
> Below is the result with a `\enlargethispage`:
>
> [image]

Comment: What is the problem with saying `\postdisplaypenalty=10000\relax` immediately after `\[` or before `\]` (for instance)? It certainly prevents the page break.

Comment: @frougon Thank you, the linked question suggested `\postdisplaypenalty=100` which does not work for me, but `\postdisplaypenalty=10000` works. However it moves the entire diagram alongside the paragraph before it to the next page, and leaves a huge space on the previous page. Perhaps `\enlargethispage` is the better solution after all...

Comment: This is beause the sample document leaves no other choice due to the `\vspace*{24.5cm}` followed by unbreakable material. The huge space on the second page is your `\vspace*{24.5cm}`...

Comment: @frougon No, I meant in my original document. The big diagram (and the paragraph before it) is completely moved to the next page, and leaves almost one third of the previous page empty. However, as I just tried, this works fine in the given MWE (like I said, the MWE is not a faithful replication of my actual situation).

Comment: Yes, you have a big unbreakable block: if it doesn't fit, then it goes to the next page. If there is enough stretchable material on the previous page, nobody notices; otherwise, an ugly underfull `\vbox` ensues. That is why LaTeX has floats. :-)

Comment: I would reword the sentence and move the `commute` before the diagram. A sentence is easier to read if it isn't split by a large diagram.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you, that's probably the best idea.

Comment: Same problem: if you rephrase as Ulrike said—which is quite reasonable—, you (morally, IMHO) have to prevent a page break between the sentence and the diagram. Then you have a big unbreakable block. Again, this calls for a float.

Comment: @frougon Wait, did you mean putting the diagram into a float, like `figure`? I haven't thought about that. Books about homological algebra have tons of diagrams, but I've never noticed how they organize those diagrams before...

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. If the diagram is small enough, I understand that you can desire not to put it in a float. But then the constraints on page breaking should be relatively easy given enough stretchable space on the “first page” (there are always difficult situations of course, that need specific consideration...). Does your `\parskip`” have a small amount of stretchability?

Comment: @Jinwen I've typeset *many* documents with math displays and I've *never* incurred in such a problem. This is exactly a place for `\enlargethispage`.

Answer (score 0):

Elements you want be typeset together can be enclosed in `minipage` but it sometimes produces unexpected gaps. It's probably better to use floats.

EDIT. In the example below, if I remove the second `The diagram`, everything is fit to one page as latex manages to shrink gaps in this particular example.

The example

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe,margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=24.5cm]{example-image}

The diagram

The diagram

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \bgroup
        \centering
        \begin{tikzcd}
            \bullet & \bullet \\
            \bullet & \bullet
            \arrow[from=1-1, to=1-2]
            \arrow[from=2-1, to=2-2]
            \arrow[from=1-1, to=2-1]
            \arrow[from=1-2, to=2-2]
        \end{tikzcd}
        \par
    \egroup
    commute.
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Comment: Thank you for this. However this approach is not essentially better than the `\postdisplaypenalty=10000` mentioned in the comments to the question, as they usually both leave a (potentially) huge space on the previous page. One is still recommended to: 1) use floats; 2) use `\enlargethispage` when necessary.

Comment: It is just an alternative way to already recommended approach with floats. I personally use them and re-phrase texts anytime I have to fit content to a page.